# Ubuntu 12.04 nVidia TwinView tearing

Tags: sync, twinview, tearing

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. Today I just purchased a second monitor (I have a Dell U2711 and a 42-inch Sony TV). I'm running the 295.49 proprietary nVidia graphics driver, my graphics card is a GeForce GTX 460.

I am not able to activate "xinerama" with "separate X screens", not sure why.

I am able to use TwinView. This works, although it results in severe tearing on the Sony TV. It's as though "sync to vblank" isn't working (I have this set in Compiz and in the nVidia settings). If I disable the Dell U2711 and only use the Sony, everything works fine, zero tearing.

Is it the case that "sync to vblank" can only work on a single monitor in Ubuntu 12.04?

Is there any way to get rid of the tearing on the second monitor in TwinView mode?

Comment: You can try using an older nvidia driver and/or use the nouveau drivers

Comment: I've tried using every previous driver that would install. It did not work.

Comment: Any indication looking through `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sync to vblank can only work for one monitor with NVIDIA and TwinView.

I found that this answer helped me fix the syncing to the monitor I wanted:

https://askubuntu.com/a/140036

Answer (score 0):

Try a newer driver version of the nvidia driver from the [xswat ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates)
looks like the version is 304.84