# html5 video glitch

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, html5

I have enabled the html5 video's in Youtube. Whenever I play a video in html5, I get to see weird horizantal lines:

[image]

I'm using the latest Google Chrome on Ubuntu 13.04. I've got a Nvidia K1000M graphics card with the latest proprietary drivers installed.
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions presented to [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/125245/221281) answer? Have you tried turning off hardware acceleration in chrome?

Comment: That's not necessarily all Ubuntu's fault (but it might be partly down to Ubuntu).

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

That's known as screen/video **tearing**. You can try to [enable or disable Vertical Sync](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFRpnQ09_LA), or set it to *Adaptive*.

If you've tried playing videos outside the browser with VLC, Totem and other applications and the problem still remains, I suggest you check this thread: [How do I stop video tearing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125245/how-do-i-stop-video-tearing-nvidia-prop-driver-non-compositing-window-manager)