# Terrible screen tearing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, screen, tearing

So I installed Ubuntu about a week ago after finally getting around to sorting out my partitions. Everything has gone great except that I get screen tearing on anything that goes fullscreen. I've searched around and tried loads of different solutions but none have worked. My GFX card is a nVidia GT 650M, I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: Are you using Nouveau or the proprietary drivers?

Comment: The propriety drivers, I had screen tearing on non-full screen video with the Nouveau drivers.

Comment: Check vsync is set in Nvidia X Server / OpenGL settings. There is a suggestion in [Seeking Information About Ubuntu 14.04 + nVidia screen tearing / vsync bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/477458/seeking-information-about-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-screen-tearing-vsync-bug). And [Have tearing (no Vsync) in movies](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456355/have-tearing-no-vsync-in-movies)

Comment: Also [How do I stop video tearing? (Nvidia prop driver, non-compositing window manager)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125245/how-do-i-stop-video-tearing-nvidia-prop-driver-non-compositing-window-manager?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Screen tearing is a very annoying problem and can be caused by different things.
Check if your vsync is enabled and check whether your monitor's refresh frequency is set to the same value as the software value.
A quick search online shows that the NVidia 650 has this problem for quite a few people. I advise you to search around and see what works for you. Different people report different methods of dealing with it.

It greatly depends on the vendor of the GPU, what other hardware, drivers and settings you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First install CompizConfig-Settings-Manager by

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Open CompizConfig-Settings-Manager find `Composite` and `check` it. Now Click `Composite` and `uncheck` the box of `Unredirect Fullscreen Windows`.
Close CompizConfig-Settings-Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having the issues with video tearing using your Nvidia card you can run the following in a terminal:
 nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"

### Worked great on a few of my machines running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Assuming you are using one video card, Alternatively you can try this config file edit in the file located at:  /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device0"
Driver "nvidia"
VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName "GeForce GTX 650"
Option "RegistryDwords" "PerfLevelSrc=0x2222"
Option "TripleBuffer" "True"
EndSection

You can change the performance level value to "PerfLevelSrc=0x2233" if your video card does not like the full performance setting above.

Answer (score 0):

This may Also help...
  Do a complete removal of existing Nvidia drivers and Config's.
I use Terminal booting to the grub recover option in the boot menu. Then an apt-get purge method, **but** you might want to look this up as I accidently put a `*` at he the end  of my command and 'FURAR'ed my system once!!!
I was there after able to install Nvidia again in a normal boot with good results. I also added the Nvidia control panel (nvidia-settings) to get better control over the card functions. Seems too much is left behind and not removed installing the drivers over the previous drivers, thus causing problems and having no Idea where you are with the drivers,
Much said about this in the search results...Perhaps too much!!!... and not very concise.

Comment: This is not a well formatted answer, will you just edit it to be better understandable?

Comment: This answer id somewhat broad because so much depends on What version and OS are used, Monitor and specific video card used, So my answer is as more of a starting point and would require the User to research their specifics. But in all cases the point was complete removal and install. However  for me removal always meant doing this by the CLI by booting into the CLI and not in a graphical mode